# Get random sets of 5 from 50

Tags: c#, .net

From a deck of 50 need to get sets of 5 as random as possible and as fast as possible.  The thought here is to shuffle to get 10 sets of five at a time with no collisions.

Int1 and Int2 will not change during a run.  If they do other bad stuff would happen.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ )
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", NextFive(11, 12)));
            int count = NextFive(11, 12).Count();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString("N0"));
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    private int[] deckBase;
    int nextFiveLastStart = 45;
    private IEnumerable<int> NextFive(int int1, int int2)
    {
        if (int1 == int2)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("int1 == int2");
        if (int1 > 51 || int2 > 51)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("int1 > 51 || int2 > 51");
        if (deckBase == null)
        {
            deckBase = new int[50];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
            {
                if (i == int1 || i == int2)
                    continue;
                deckBase[j] = i;
                j++;
            }
        }
        if (nextFiveLastStart >= 45)
        {
            nextFiveLastStart = 0;
            // Yates shuffle
            for (int i = 49; i >= 1; i--)
            {
                int j = rand.Next(i + 1);
                if (j != i)
                {   // exchange values
                    int curVal = deckBase[i];
                    deckBase[i] = deckBase[j];
                    deckBase[j] = curVal;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            nextFiveLastStart += 5;
        return deckBase.Skip(nextFiveLastStart).Take(5);
    }
```

Comment: It isn't completely clear to me why you want to shuffle the deck each time? If you shuffle the deck once sufficiently randomly, just choose 5 cards and remove them from a `List`. That way the card isn't in the deck anymore so you can't have collisions and it was shuffled randomly once. What does `int1` and `int2` represent? Those aren't very descriptive names?

Comment: Why are you using a deck of 50 cards? A common deck is 52 cards.

Comment: @RonBeyer It does not shuffle the deck each time.   Int1 and Int2 are removed from the deck.

Comment: @tinstaafl If you examine the question there are 52 and 2 are removed.

Comment: Need to add || int1 < 0 || int2 < 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>  private IEnumerable<int> NextFive(int int1, int int2)
> ```

The names `int1` and `int2` give absolutely no clue about what they are good for. I tried to ready the code but I cannot figure it out. Looking at `if (i == int1 || i == int2)` I guess it means *exclude* but who knows.

---

> ```
> throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("int1 == int2");
> ```

This isn't `IndexOutOfRangeException` but rather `ArgumentException`. The argumetns have invalid values but they might be within the allowed range.

---

> ```
> throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("int1 > 51 || int2 > 51");
> ```

I agree this is the right type of the exception but I preferred it checking each value separately to give the user a hint which one of the parameters is incorrect.

---

> ```
> Random rand = new Random();
> private int[] deckBase;
> int nextFiveLastStart = 45;
> ```

Inconsistent access modifier usage. private implicit, private explicit, private implicit... Pick one ;-)

---

> ```
> int j = 0;
> for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
> {
>     if (i == int1 || i == int2)
>         continue;
>     deckBase[j] = i;
>     j++;
> }
> ```

There's no need for the `int j = 0;` you can put it inside the `for`:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 52; i++)
{
    if (i == int1 || i == int2)
        continue;
    deckBase[j] = i;
    j++;
}
```

Comment: Thing is "int1 == int2" would result in an index out of range exception in deckBase

Comment: @Paparazzi I mean the check is legitimate but the exception type is wrong. I preferred ArgumentException saying that the parameters must not be equal and actually the out-of-range test should take place first.

Answer (score 2):

1. This isn't really production code, is it? There's an obvious test method which is testing a private method. What should be the API?
2. The chunks of five are returned as

   ```
       return deckBase.Skip(nextFiveLastStart).Take(5);
   ```

   There are at least two problems with this line. Firstly, `Skip` is slow. You're losing the constant-time access of the array. Secondly, it's a lazy enumerable which keeps a reference to `deckBase`. If I call `NextFive` twenty times, hanging on to the return values each time, and then enumerate them as so:

   ```
   var seqs = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).
       Select(i => TakeFive(11, 12)).
       ToArray();
   seqs = seqs.Select(seq => seq.ToArray());
   ```

   then I'll only have ten distinct sequences (as compared by `SequenceEqual`).

I can't suggest concrete changes without rewriting the entire code, but I think it does need to be completely rewritten with a public API and eager enumerations.

Comment: Does it have to be production code to be in Code Review?  It will be used as a private method.  What is wrong with that?   I will not be using the code as you depict.

Comment: It doesn't have to be for use in production, but if it's throwaway code then why would you ask for it to be reviewed? So I think it's the default expectation that code will be held to the *standard* of production code. And if there are particular external factors which mean that a bug isn't exercised, that doesn't mean that it's not a bug, although it could justify not fixing it *provided that the limitations on use are clearly documented*.

Comment: Returning ToList() increased execution time by 50%.   The stated question is as fast as possible.  Code is either production or throw away? Thanks for your time and input.

Comment: If you mean just adding `ToList` to the existing code, I wouldn't expect that to improve the speed: just the correctness. But using a `List<>` rather than an array and calling `GetRange` would probably be faster.

Comment: I hope you don't expect ToList() to improve speed as it adds 50% execution time. Don't agree that IEnumerable is incorrect. Again thanks for your time and input.